# Rails + Unicorn + Heroku + Asset Pipeline Assets not being served to calls from outside the website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline, unicorn

I've got a stack with **Rails** and **Unicorn** running on **Heroku**, I'm serving the assets statically so I can configure **Cloudfront**.

When **Cloudfront** tries to request some asset unicorn is raising an error, I checked unicorn's source code and apparently the `body` is coming with `nil` value, the most intriguing part is that when the assets are requested from within the site, in the browser, they are served just fine. I also ran `curl mypage.com/assets/some_asset.css` and it raised the exact same error in Rails' log. The following are the errors showing up on Rails' logs and the error I got when I ran curl from my machine.

```
2013-12-09T15:43:25.758765+00:00 app[web.1]: E, [2013-12-09T15:43:25.758676 #15] ERROR -- : app error: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
2013-12-09T15:43:25.758842+00:00 app[web.1]: E, [2013-12-09T15:43:25.758775 #15] ERROR -- : /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.7.0/lib/unicorn/http_response.rb:60:in `http_response_write'
2013-12-09T15:43:25.758892+00:00 app[web.1]: E, [2013-12-09T15:43:25.758811 #15] ERROR -- : /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.7.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:590:in `process_client'
2013-12-09T15:43:25.758936+00:00 app[web.1]: E, [2013-12-09T15:43:25.758868 #15] ERROR -- : /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.7.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:660:in `worker_loop'
2013-12-09T15:43:25.759023+00:00 app[web.1]: E, [2013-12-09T15:43:25.758945 #15] ERROR -- : /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.7.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:527:in `spawn_missing_workers'
2013-12-09T15:43:25.759023+00:00 app[web.1]: E, [2013-12-09T15:43:25.758991 #15] ERROR -- : /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.7.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:153:in `start'
2013-12-09T15:43:25.759023+00:00 app[web.1]: E, [2013-12-09T15:43:25.759016 #15] ERROR -- : /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.7.0/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
2013-12-09T15:43:25.759089+00:00 app[web.1]: E, [2013-12-09T15:43:25.759041 #15] ERROR -- : /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
2013-12-09T15:43:25.759089+00:00 app[web.1]: E, [2013-12-09T15:43:25.759066 #15] ERROR -- : /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
```

Error I got from curl:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
curl: (18) transfer closed with 4283 bytes remaining to read
```

This could be due to unicorn's configuration being set to 30 seconds, but the error happens really quick, not even a full second passes.

Edit I: Because I'm using Heroku, and my app has **lots of assets** it is not possible to compile all of them before Heroku times out, therefore I'm compiling the assets locally and pushing them to Heroku.

Comment: So you are precompiling the assets, when you deploy it to Heroku, right?

Comment: Yes, that is right. They are all precompiled.

Comment: You should see the name of the stylesheet that the browser is serving up, using Chrome's inspector. You will see that Rails has attached some string to your CSS file to bust browser cache.

Comment: Use curl -v and Chrome's Developer Tools to get complete, raw requests for both cases. Paste them here.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found out what the problem was.

For some reason when a request wasn't coming from a web browser, the way the app access memcached is different, since my memcached server was disabled it was throwing that, completely unrelated, error. Thank you for you help!